# Ubuntu in dual-boot doesn't start after reinstalling Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I was in dual-boot using Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows

I have recently re-installed Windows, and now I'm having troubles booting Ubuntu. It is always booting Windows and not showing options to choose between Windows and Ubuntu (Windows starts automatically).

How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Windows disable Fast Boot:

> - Search for and open “Power options” in the Start Menu.
> - Click “Choose what the power buttons do” on the left side of the window.
> - Click “Change settings that are currently unavailable.”
> - Under “Shutdown settings” uncheck “Turn on fast startup”.

Then boot from a live Ubuntu CD (or USB) then install Boot repair tool

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Run boot repair by typing `boot-repair` command then click on Recommended repair button.
Good luck.